# How to secure a ROO generated finder?

Tags: spring-security, spring-roo

What is the ideal approach to secure a finder generated by ROO? I'd like to be able to add a @Secured annotation without a push-in refactor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `applicationContext-security.xml` either providing AsssspectJ's `<protect-pointcut />` as [in documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) or protecting URL's with [expression based syntax](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization).